# Do Documents inherit from site property bag values?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search, search-scope, managed-property

We're setting up multiple sites for each of our projects. We're using the Property bag to save information about the Project, like project status and such things.

We're then mapping those properties to managed properties so they can be indexed and the site can return them in search.

I'm wondering however, will I be able to query documents in my Search Center based on managed properties in the property bag?

So for example, if I have Project A and that title is a managed property. Inside that project site, there's a document library and file called Budget.

In Search Center, can I do a query for "Budget" then refine by "Project A"? Does the document inherit from the property bag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Though since you are using the Property Bag you are probably already using custom code. (Personally I would use a "Project Status" content Type in a list on the site. This way you don't need to mess with the property bag at all and it's easy to edit.)

Either way, you will need to execute a second query after retrieving the Project Site result and pass the URL Path of the desired site to further refine the search to only documents in that site.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by using the Project Status Content Type on my site. I have multiple sites, each site is 1 project. I need a way to identify different projects base on status or other properties through search center. I don't see how Content Type would help here but if you can elaborate that would be useful.

Comment: I show this all the time in sessions. I need to write up a blog post. I create a list in every site that is a Project Site. In that List I have a Content Type, call it Project Status. Then I have the Project lead fill in the details. Following a crawl I can search for ContentType="Project Status" and get all the sites. WAY easier that working with the Property Bag and it is supported in Office 365.

Comment: Would the idea still be the same if the Content Type was more generic like "Project Data" then I'd have various columns for each property I'm trying to track relating to my project?

Comment: Yes, then you could create Search Refiners based on the Data.